# Aspose - Issue in Auto table Resize, Fit to Page

Tags: pdf, aspose, aspose.words

We are facing a table Re-sizeable issue in our project.

Library - aspose.words

Issue:
We are using aspose for generating PDF document, In our pdf there are multiple tables. Currently, if a table is too large to fit on a page, it will run off the page. We want to implement automatic scaling for these tables, automatic scaling such that if table is too large then it can automatically adjust the width, font inside the table such that it always fit in to the page.

Also while investigating I found one property Autofit but it is not useful for my scenario because this doesn’t change the font-size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, in your case, you can try using [Document.Updatetablelayout](https://apireference.aspose.com/words/net/aspose.words/document/methods/updatetablelayout) method to calculate actual table width and then check if the table fits the page. In the following example I created a simple table that exits the page bounds and then updated the table to make it fit the page. In the example a simplified method for scaling font size is used, it is better to use [DocumentVisitor](https://apireference.aspose.com/words/net/aspose.words/documentvisitor) to do this.

```cs
Document doc = new Document();
DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);

// Build a simple table that exits page bounds. 
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
    {
        builder.InsertCell();
        builder.Write("Test");
    }
    builder.EndRow();
}
Table t = builder.EndTable();

// If you check width of cells in the created table before calling this method, width will be zero,
// this means auto-width. After calling this method width of cells is updated and it is possible to calculate actual table width.
doc.UpdateTableLayout();

// Calculate width of the table.
double tableWidth = 0;
foreach (Cell c in t.FirstRow.Cells)
    tableWidth += c.CellFormat.Width;

Section tableParentSection = (Section)t.GetAncestor(NodeType.Section);
if (tableWidth > tableParentSection.PageSetup.ContentWidth)
{
    double fontRatio = tableParentSection.PageSetup.ContentWidth / tableWidth;

    // Change font in the table.
    // Note: this is rood mothod to change font size only for demonstration purposes.
    // I would recommend you to use DocumentVisitor to change font size.
    NodeCollection paragraphs = t.GetChildNodes(NodeType.Paragraph, true);
    foreach (Paragraph p in paragraphs)
    {
        p.ParagraphBreakFont.Size *= fontRatio;
        foreach (Run r in p.Runs)
            r.Font.Size *= fontRatio;
    }
}

doc.Save(@"C:\Temp\out.pdf");
```

Here is how table looks without updating its content 
[image]
After updating font size it looks like this
[image]

Hope this helps.

Disclosure: I work at Aspose.Words team.